# lambda function not parsing my simple json object

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to Lambda but I have been trying to set up a simple json object and I get the following error, parsing error, unexpected token.

my code is, which I have tested and it is valid json:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": "1"
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "elementType": "html",
            "focal": false,
            "html": "<div>My Lambda Object</div>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Its confusing because even there own examples return the same message. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the lambda code? What exact errors do you get?

Comment: It's related to Amazon Web Services, In their words: AWS Lambda is a serverless compute service that lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers, error is: parsing error, unexpected token.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, it expects you to return the object:

```
return{
    "metadata": {
        "version": "1"
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "elementType": "html",
            "focal": false,
            "html": "<div>Test My Lamda Function</div>"
        }
    ]
};
```